# Writing tables in HTML

Tags: html

[image: uhren]:

So I need to build this kind of a site without using anything but HTML (no CSS). And I'm having issues aligning the upper text (I can only use align="right" but it puts it and the end of the site), and I can't seem to make that table. Here's my code so far:

```
<html>
    <p size="12px" align="right"><b>Janez Novak</b></p>
    <table border="1" style="width:20%">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width=><p align="center" rowspan="5"><b>test</b></p><br/></td>
            <td>um feri</td>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width=><p align="left"><b>Telefon</b></p></td>
            <td>+386 2 220 7000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width=><p align="left"><b>Telefaks</b></p></td>
            <td>+386 2 220 7272, +386 2 220 7090</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: No CSS, yet you use an inline `style` attribute for the `<table>` element?!

Comment: How do I make it smaller then?

Comment: You did it - with CSS. HTML will not let you resize tables.

Comment: Did it with <table border="1" width="20%">

Comment: Yes but that hasn't been valid HTML for many years. If you want custom styling (and HTML which is valid in our time), then you are going to need to use style sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem:

```
<html><body>
    <table width="600" align="Center">
        <tr><td align="center">
                <h1>Janez Novak</h1>
                <i>Univ. dipl. inz. | Univ. dipl. ing.</i>
                <h2>Raziskovalec | Researcher</h2>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td align="Left">
            <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" align="Center" valign="Top"><b>Naslov:</b></td>
                <td>UM FERI</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Smetanova Ulica</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2000 Maribor</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><b>Telefon:</b></td>
                <td>+386 2 220 7000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><b>Telefaks:</b></td>
                <td>+386 2 220 7272, +386 2 220 7090</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" colspan="2"><a href="www.feri.um.si">www.feri.um.si</a></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</body></html>
```

Now the result looks like this:

[image]

Note that you also have to remove `style="width:20%"` because that's CSS.

Comment: It works for the table, but if you see the image the text has to be near the table("Janez Novak")

Comment: OK, that's not difficult, I'll adapt the example.

Comment: Hm the text is only directly above the table if I zoom in the site to 180%

Comment: Isn't that the nature of HTML? Maybe you want to use absolute widths.

Comment: But how? In the table or in the div?

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer and you'll find out.

Answer (score 0):

`rowspan` is not a valid attribute of `<p>` elements. In order to replicate what is shown in your image, use the following code:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 50%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" rowspan="3"><b>Address:</b></td>
        <td>1 Test Street</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Testington</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Testshire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><b>Telefon:</b></td>
        <td>+386 2 220 7000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><b>Telefaks:</b></td>
        <td>+386 2 220 7272, +386 2 220 7090</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wwncub8g/)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, there's an error in your HTML in your table:

```
<table border="1" style="width:20%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width=><p align="center" rowspan="5"><b>test</b></p><br/></td>
        <td>um feri</td>
    </tr> <!-- Added missing tr closing tag -->
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width=><p align="left"><b>Telefon</b></p></td>
        <td>+386 2 220 7000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width=><p align="left"><b>Telefaks</b></p></td>
        <td>+386 2 220 7272, +386 2 220 7090</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Second: How is it that you can't use CSS, but are using the `style` attribute on your table, this is *virtually the same* as CSS.

Third, a possibility here is to wrap the `<table>` in a `<p>` or a `<div>` and move the entire parent element

Comment: `rowspan` is not a valid attribute for `<p>` elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

Comment: @BenM I must've missed this one